# Concatenation of strings and variables in x86

Tags: x86, nasm, x86-16

I am trying to concatenate string and variable and store it into new variable in x86.
I am using nasm to write assembly code.
What I wanna do is something like this:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = "values are: " + a + " and " + b ;
print c;
```

But I dont know how I can concatenate and assign value to new variable

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> a = 1;
> b = 2;
> c = "values are: " + a + " and " + b ;
> ```

This data roughly translates to:

```
a db 1
b db 2
c db "values are: ? and ?$"
```

Your variables *a* and *b* are numbers. You need to convert these into text before inserting them in the string which, in this simplified example, uses the question mark character (**?**) as a single character placeholder.

```
mov al, [a]       ;AL becomes 1
add al, '0'       ;AL becomes "1"
mov [c + 12], al  ;12 is offset of the first '?'
mov al, [b]       ;AL becomes 2
add al, '0'       ;AL becomes "2"
mov [c + 18], al  ;18 is offset of the second '?'
mov dx, c         ;Address of the string
mov ah, 09h
int 21h           ;Print with DOS
```

---

This is an alternative to the above code. It's a few instructions shorter but has the drawback of not being too reusable! (Because the `add` 's depend on the placeholders remaining zero)

```
a db 1
b db 2
c db "values are: 0 and 0$"


mov al, [a]       ;AL becomes 1
add [c + 12], al  ;12 is offset of the first '0'
mov al, [b]       ;AL becomes 2
add [c + 18], al  ;18 is offset of the second '0'
mov dx, c         ;Address of the string
mov ah, 09h
int 21h           ;Print with DOS
```

Comment: does this same code will work with 0x80 interrupt if i change it to appropriate registers?

Comment: @lunatic955: Linux `sys_write` needs a pointer + length, not a `$` terminator, but the basic logic of doing byte adds into the placeholder string is obviously universal.